# Hibernate query subtyped entity by natural-id

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, jpa, natural-key

I use Hibernate and want to query for entities by their natural identifier. However, it seems not to be possible to have natural ids on subtypes. I have two classes A and B where B extends A:

```
class A {
  long id;
}

class B extends A {
  String naturalId;
}
```

`A` is mapped in Hibernate with its own identifier. `B` is mapped as joined subclass. However, it is not possible to map the natural identifier of `B` in Hibernate because the mapping of `B` is a subclass mapping.

- Why is it not possible to have a natural identifier on the subclass `B`? Note that I don't want Hibernate to generate my database schema, I just want to have natural ids for fast cache hits.
- Is there a way/a best practice to have natural ids on subtypes for fast second level cache querying?

  - Is this still possible when natural ids might get updated (change) in rare circumstances and the cache has to be maintained in a clustered Java EE environment?

Answer (score 1):

1. NaturalId only make sense for base classes, because you can't retrieve a sub-class without the base class info.

   Let's say you could map map both the base class and the sub-class with a natural-id:

   ```
   class A {
     long id;
     String baseId;
   }

   class B extends A {
     String naturalId;
   }

   A a = session.bySimpleNaturalId( A.class ).load( "abc" );
   ```

   If the entity we retrieve if of type B, it's not clear which of the natural-id variants will be used.
2. You can't fetch a sub-class without getting the base-class info. So when you load a Sub-class from cache, the associated base-class info is retrieved as well. Therefore you could have the base class store the natural-id, or simply use the primary key for caching.
3. You can update the natural-id, although a [business key](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/) should be immutable. For *mutable* natural-ids you need to use the [mutable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/NaturalId.html#mutable%28%29) attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't see why Hibernate shouldn't know which natural-id to use, because we're explicitly giving the type of the entity to query. Also defining a natural-id with same signature as the natural-id of a parent class could easily be forbidden.

Comment: I think this decision was taken for simplicity sake. From an  implementation point of view, it's doable to implement some work-around to override the base class natural-id from a sub-class. You can file a Hibernate issue for this situation on Hibernate JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

According to [13.3. Entity inheritance and second-level cache mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-mappings-inheritance):

> As of Hibernate ORM 5.3, you can now override a base class @Cacheable
>   or @Cache definition at subclass level.

so you might have a chance by resetting the caching annotations on `B`.
I never tried it so please confirm the solution with a comment.